# Remote Desktop Not Working on Hadoop on Azure

Tags: azure, hadoop

I am able to allocate a Hadoop cluster on Windows Azure by entering my Windows Live ID, but after that, I am unable to do Remote Desktop to the master node there.
Before the cluster creation, it's showing a message that says "Microsoft has got overwhelming positive feedback from Hadoop On Azure users, hence it's giving a free trial for 5 days with 2 slave nodes."
[P.S. that this Preview Version of HoA was working before]

Any suggestions for this problem?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

When you created your Hadoop cluster, you were asked to enter the DNS name for cluster which could something like your_hadoop_cluster.cloudapp.net.

So first please ping to your Hadoop cluster name to see if it returns back an IP address, this will prove if you really have any cluster configured at all. IF you dont get an IP back then you don't have a Hadoop cluster on Azure and trying creating one.

IF you are sure you do have a Hadoop cluster on Winodws Azure, try to post your question the following Hadoop on Azure CTP forum and you will get proper help you need:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/HadoopOnAzureCTP/

Comment: I am unable to ping my cluster using its DNS name, and even i m unable to ping hadooponazure.com as well ... kindly suggest..